# S3/Lambda - Scanning entire bucket for key name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

In my S3 bucket there are a couple thousand pictures. Is there a way to get a specific key name without going over each photo?

I'm doing this because I'm uploading images one by one through presigned URls, and since it only allows one object upload per URL, I need to scan the s3 bucket in my post upload lambda function after each successful upload to check if the complete set of images has been uploaded so I can record the URLs into my DB. This is because I want the user to successfully uploaded all the photos saved to the DB, or none to be saved.

Comment: S3 has notification for the put object event.You can write a lambda function to record the object which was uploaded and save that in the DB

Comment: Yeah I know that, but my problem is how do I guarantee all the pictures are uploaded? I don't want three out of 5 images recorded if my network fails during upload

Comment: A put notification is only send only if the upload was successful and not otherwise

Comment: That's not my question...I'm trying to ensure that the presigned urls are all uploaded successfully and recorded or none.

Comment: A curl in Lambda?

Comment: S3 does not have search for a key functionality as of yet.But you can hit a HTTP GET or POST request on the object url and if it does not return a 404 that means the object is uploaded.

Comment: does that help? updated comment

Comment: You presumably mean that you are searching for a filename, not a key. A key uniquely identifies an object and provides constant time access, with no need to search. If you're simply trying to detect when the N'th upload has happened, use S3 events to trigger a Lambda and increment an Atomic Counter in DynamoDB. When that counter reaches N, trigger your post-processing step. Give each collection of N images a unique key (e.g. a UUID) that you use as the key of the atomic counter item.